# Azure REST API equivalent for az webapp list-runtimes

Tags: azure, go, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am unable to find any REST API equivalent for this azure cli command:

```
az webapp list-runtimes
```

I am looking for it's support in Golang SDK here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go

Any suggestions on how to fetch list of runtimes supported by Azure using Go SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>It seems there is no method in Go SDK to list runtimes for web app,</del> the REST API equivalent for this azure cli is this - [`Provider - Get Available Stacks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/provider/getavailablestacks), you can call the API via Go directly.

Sample:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Web/availableStacks?osTypeSelected=Linux&api-version=2019-08-01

GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Web/availableStacks?osTypeSelected=Windows&api-version=2019-08-01
```

To get the token used to call the REST API, [register an AD App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal), [Get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret).

Then navigate to the portal -> your subscription -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> add your AD App as an RBAC role e.g. `Contributor`, `Owner`, details follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

In the code, use [`ClientCredentialsConfig`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth#ClientCredentialsConfig) via the values got before to get the token, then you can use the token to call the REST API, details about auth, refer to - [Use an authentication client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/go/azure-sdk-authorization#use-an-authentication-client). You could also use other auth methods, it depends on your requirement.

**Update:**

Looks azure-go-sdk has providers client which can be used to get available stacks.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/master/services/web/mgmt/2020-06-01/web/provider.go#L45

Comment: I see azure-go-sdk has providers client which can be used to get available stacks as well. Here's the link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/master/services/web/mgmt/2020-06-01/web/provider.go#L45

Comment: @Puru Sorry for my oversight, updated it in the answer.

Comment: @joyWang Would you suggest using the Azure.Net SDK or go directly with the rest API calls. I have a need to do automated code deployment to app service. I am confused, should I stick with Rest Management APIs, Azure.net SDK or Fluent.